# How to send audio file from front end to django backend through websockets for processing at the backend

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, stream, web-mediarecorder

I have made a website in django that uses websockets to perform certain tasks as follows :

- From frontend I want to take audio using MediaRecorder as input api through javascript
- I want to send this audio back to the backend for processing and that processed data is again send back through the connection in realtime.

I have tried various things for the purpose but haven't been successful yet. The bytes data that I've been receiving at the backend when I'm converting that into audio then I'm getting the length and size of the audio file but not getting the content of the file. Means the whole audio is silent but the same audio which I'm listening in the frontend is having some sound. but I don't know what's happening at the backend with the file.

Consumer.py :

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
 
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["username"]
        self.room_group_name = "realtime_%s" % self.room_name

        self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()
        print("Connected")

    async def disconnect(self , close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.roomGroupName ,
            self.channel_layer
        )
        print("Disconnected")
 
     async def receive(self, bytes_data):
        with open('myfile.wav', mode='bx') as f:
            f.write(bytes_data)
```

audio.js :

```
<script>
           navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((stream) => {
            if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm'))
                return alert('Browser not supported')

            const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
                mimeType: 'audio/webm',
            })

            const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/audio')

            socket.onopen = () => {
                document.querySelector('#status').textContent = 'Connected'
                console.log({ event: 'onopen' })
                mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', async (event) => {
                    if (event.data.size > 0 && socket.readyState == 1) {
                        socket.send(event.data)
                    }
            })
            mediaRecorder.start(250)
            }

            socket.onmessage = (message) => {
                const received = message.data
                if (received) {
                    console.log(received)              
                }
           }

           socket.onclose = () => {
            console.log({ event: 'onclose' })
        }

            socket.onerror = (error) => {
                console.log({ event: 'onerror', error })
            }

           })

        </script>
```

Comment: it's interesting you made the event handler `async` for no reason ... but, you can have a reason ... rather than sending a blob, send the actual data, `socket.send(await event.data.arrayBuffer())`

Comment: No its still not working the audio file is still corrupted at the backend

Comment: Here my arrayBuffer() object Promise is shown at the backend terminal